# Looping through torch_geometric.loader.DataLoader Object

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm trying to loop through a DataLoader object. However, I keep getting a torch.cat() issue when I loop through just this specific list.

listOfData containts all torch_geometric.data.data.Data objects.

The following code is how I created the DataLoader object.

```
np.random.seed(seed)
np.random.shuffle(listOfData)
train_loader = DataLoader(listOfData[:int((length0.80))], batch_size=batch_size_train)
test_loader = DataLoader(listOfData[int((length0.80)):], batch_size=batch_size_test)
```

Then when I try to loop through the DataLoader.

```
for i in train_loader:
    print(i)
```

It prints out a few graphs and then comes up with this error:

```
Batch(x=[462, 300], edge_index=[2, 223], y=[13], batch=[462], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[501, 300], edge_index=[2, 247], y=[13], batch=[501], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[764, 300], edge_index=[2, 370], y=[13], batch=[764], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[490, 300], edge_index=[2, 236], y=[13], batch=[490], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[353, 300], edge_index=[2, 169], y=[13], batch=[353], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[452, 300], edge_index=[2, 215], y=[13], batch=[452], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[375, 300], edge_index=[2, 161], y=[13], batch=[375], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[622, 300], edge_index=[2, 336], y=[13], batch=[622], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[355, 300], edge_index=[2, 177], y=[13], batch=[355], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[506, 300], edge_index=[2, 132], y=[13], batch=[506], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[486, 300], edge_index=[2, 176], y=[13], batch=[486], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[534, 300], edge_index=[2, 266], y=[13], batch=[534], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[540, 300], edge_index=[2, 252], y=[13], batch=[540], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[560, 300], edge_index=[2, 247], y=[13], batch=[560], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[600, 300], edge_index=[2, 269], y=[13], batch=[600], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[486, 300], edge_index=[2, 220], y=[13], batch=[486], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[228, 300], edge_index=[2, 88], y=[13], batch=[228], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[473, 300], edge_index=[2, 191], y=[13], batch=[473], ptr=[14])
Batch(x=[322, 300], edge_index=[2, 142], y=[13], batch=[322], ptr=[14])
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_4277/2753664710.py in
----> 1 for i in train_loader:
2 print(i)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in next(self)
519 if self._sampler_iter is None:
520 self._reset()
--> 521 data = self._next_data()
522 self._num_yielded += 1
523 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
559 def _next_data(self):
560 index = self._next_index() # may raise StopIteration
--> 561 data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index) # may raise StopIteration
562 if self._pin_memory:
563 data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
45 else:
46 data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 47 return self.collate_fn(data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/loader/dataloader.py in call(self, batch)
37
38 def call(self, batch):
---> 39 return self.collate(batch)
40
41

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/loader/dataloader.py in collate(self, batch)
18 if isinstance(elem, Data) or isinstance(elem, HeteroData):
19 return Batch.from_data_list(batch, self.follow_batch,
---> 20 self.exclude_keys)
21 elif isinstance(elem, torch.Tensor):
22 return default_collate(batch)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/batch.py in from_data_list(cls, data_list, follow_batch, exclude_keys)
67 add_batch=True,
68 follow_batch=follow_batch,
---> 69 exclude_keys=exclude_keys,
70 )
71

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/collate.py in collate(cls, data_list, increment, add_batch, follow_batch, exclude_keys)
75 # Collate attributes into a unified representation:
76 value, slices, incs = _collate(attr, values, data_list, stores,
---> 77 increment)
78
79 out_store[attr] = value

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/collate.py in _collate(key, values, data_list, stores, increment)
146 incs = None
147
--> 148 value = torch.cat(values, dim=cat_dim or 0)
149 return value, slices, incs
150

RuntimeError: torch.cat(): Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 1 and 2
```

I'm very stuck, if someone could please help me.

```
Environment
PyTorch version: (torch.__version__): 1.9.1+cu111
OS (e.g., Linux): Jupyter Notebook
Python version (e.g., 3.9): 3.7
How you installed PyTorch and PyG (conda, pip, source): pip
```

How I imported:

```
from torch_geometric.loader import DataLoader
```

Answer (score 0):

It's attempting to concatenate tensors of differing numbers of dimensions. This occurs when it's attempting to collate your samples into a batch. This is likely due to the samples being torch tensors of differing dimensions.